# chaining `fs.readdir` with a `.then` to return an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to create an array of specific files in a directory; which will go through a few test cases to make sure it fits a given criteria.

I'm using the `fs.readdir` method, but it doesn't return a `promise` meaning I cannot `push` to an `array`.

My idea was to populate an array (`arr`) with the files I actually want to output and then do something with that array. But because `readdir` is asynchronous and I can't chain a `.then()` onto it, my plans are quashed.

I've also tried the same thing with `readdirSync` to no avail.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

var arr = [];

fs.readdirAsync(folder).then( files => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    fs.stat(folder + '/' + file, (err, stats) => {
       if(!stats.isDirectory()) {
         arr.push(file);
        return;
      }
     });
   });
})
.then( () => {
  console.log(arr);
});
```

Comment: Why can't you use a callback? --- May you edit your question to include a [mcve] of your efforts?

Comment: _"I've also tried the same thing with readdirSync to no avail"_. That function will _return_ an array of filenames, which seems to me is exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: Have added an example of what I'm trying to do. `arr` returns `[]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out; I just needed to use `statSync` instead of `stat`

```
const fs = require('fs');

var arr = [];

var files = fs.readdirSync(folder);

files.forEach(file => {
  let fileStat = fs.statSync(folder + '/' + file).isDirectory();
  if(!fileStat) {
    arr.push(file);
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

`fs.readdir` is callback based, so you can either `promisify` it using bluebird or Node.js `util` package (or writing a simple implementation of it yourself), or simply wrap the call in a promise, like so:

```
// Wrapped in a promise
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return fs.readdir('/folderpath', (err, filenames) => err != null ? reject(err) : resolve(filenames))
})
```

Or the custom `promisify` function:

```
// Custom promisify
function promisify(fn) {
  /**
   * @param {...Any} params The params to pass into *fn*
   * @return {Promise<Any|Any[]>}
   */
  return function promisified(...params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => fn(...params.concat([(err, ...args) => err ? reject(err) : resolve( args.length < 2 ? args[0] : args )])))
  }
}

const readdirAsync = promisify(fs.readdir)
readdirAsync('./folderpath').then(filenames => console.log(filenames))
```

Comment: I have tried adding a promise, but the `arr` array still returns `[]`. I've added an example which will hopefully clear up what I'm doing. This is the first time using `readddir` so it's entirely possible I'm using it wrong.

Comment: I had to do err !== null, but this worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: ```err ? reject(err) : resolve(filenames)``` => made the first code functioning since err returned null for me!

Comment: Oh shoot, not sure why I did `!== undefined`, the default behaviour is returning `null`... Updated my answer

Answer (score 12):

Just plain javascript, no libs:

```js
function foo (folder, enconding) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readdir(folder,enconding, function(err, filenames){
            if (err) 
                reject(err); 
            else 
                resolve(filenames);
        });
    });
};
```

e.g

```js
foo(someFolder, "someEncoding")
.then((files) => console.log(files))
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 4):

As of Node.js v10, there is an [`fs.promises`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options) API that supports this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

var arr = [];

fs.promises.readdir(folder).then( files => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    fs.stat(folder + '/' + file, (err, stats) => {
       if(!stats.isDirectory()) {
         arr.push(file);
        return;
      }
     });
   });
})
.then( () => {
  console.log(arr);
});
```

Comment: you can use `fs.promises.stat(folder)` to make it all promise ( and use `async/await`

Answer (score 4):

You can now use **ES6 destructuring assignment** ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)) :

```
const
    fs = require('fs'),
    FILES = [...fs.readdirSync('src/myfolder')];

console.log(FILES);
```

Comment: That's beautiful

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use a promise instead of a callback you can promisify `fs`.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

fs.readdirAsync('./some').then()
```

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html

Comment: Have just added an example of what I'm trying to do - in the last `.then()` the `arr` returns as `[]`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) module?

Answer (score 1):

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return fs.readdir('/folderpath', (err, filenames) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(filenames))
})
```

Do not `err !== undefined` because err is actually `null`!!

Comment: You can actually simplify it even more. As you only have one statement and you're using an arrow function, you can remove the braces and the 'return' and it will work just fine.