# NodeJS: Confusion about async "readdir" and "stat"

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, fs

In the docs it shows two versions of [readdir](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) and [stat](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback). Both of which have an async and sync version `readir/readdirSync` and `stat/statSync`.

Because `readidir` and `stat` are async I would expect them to return a Promise but when trying to use `async/await` the script doesnt wait for `readdir` to resolve and if I use `.then/.catch` I get an error `cannot read .then of undefined`.

All I'm trying to do here is map the directories that exist inside of the directory the script is being ran inside of to the `dirsOfCurrentDir` map.

## Returns error `cannot read .then of undefined`

```
const fs = require('fs');

const directory = `${ __dirname }/${ process.argv[2] }`;
const dirsOfCurrentDir = new Map();

fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
  let path;

  if (err)
    return console.log(err);

  files.forEach(file => {
    path = directory + file;

    fs.stat(path, (err, stats) => {
      if (err)
        return console.log(err);

      dirsOfCurrentDir.set(file, directory);
    });
  });
}).then(() => console.log('adasdasd'))

console.log(dirsOfCurrentDir)
```

## Returns `Map {}`

```
const foo = async () => {
  await fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
    let path;

    if (err)
      return console.log(err);

    files.forEach(file => {
      path = directory + file;

      fs.stat(path, (err, stats) => {
        if (err)
          return console.log(err);

        dirsOfCurrentDir.set(file, directory);
      });
    });
  });
};

foo()
console.log(dirsOfCurrentDir)
```

## Edit

I ended up going with the synchronous versions of both of these functions `readdirSync` and `statSync`. While I would feel better using the async methods or promisify I still have not figured out how to get my code working correctly using either.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const directory = `${ __dirname }/${ process.argv[2] }`;
const dirsOfCurrentDir = new Map();

const dirContents = fs.readdirSync(directory);

dirContents.forEach(file => {
  const path = directory + file;
  const stats = fs.statSync(path);

  if (stats.isDirectory())
    dirsOfCurrentDir.set(file, path);
});

console.log(dirsOfCurrentDir); // logs out the map with all properties set
```

Comment: The `callback` parameter of `readdir` is the function you would pass into the `.then`. It doesn't return a Promise as indicated by the docs

Comment: If you want a `Promise` you need to promisify

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019316/chaining-fs-readdir-with-a-then-to-return-an-array perhaps you should look at this

Comment: @pushkin I must be missing something but I don't see where it says that https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback . Is there a different version of the docs I'm not seeing?

Comment: FYI, info on [how to promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) is under the Util section, not file system. Or you could use the new [v10 fs promises api](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api)

Comment: Seems like you're confusing `async` functions with async (asynchronous) functions.

Comment: `Because readidir and stat are async I would expect them to return a Promise` - That's the wrong expectation. You should expect to **pass a callback** to async functions. For example, the promise design pattern (which Promise implements) return an object that implement a function called `then()` that you can pass a callback to. `readdir` and `stat` directly accept a callback instead of returning a promise object.

Comment: @estus Not sure I'm following. If there is a difference between async and asynchronous then you are absolutely correct but at this moment I see relate async => asynchronous.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield It doesn't explicitly say that it doesn't return anything, but it returned something it would explicitly say that (e.g. "returns a Promise"). Since it doesn't say that, then you can't assume that it returns a promise

Comment: @BrandonBenefield All `async` functions are asynchronous, but not all asynchronous functions are `async`. Since 'async' is a common abbreviation for 'asynchronous', this can be misleading, so the context matters. Considering that native `async` functions emerged around 2017, you can judge by a timestamp. Incidentally, `fs.promises` functions that were mentioned here are in fact `async`.

Comment: Uhhh, on stack overflow you are not supposed to add your answer to your question.  Questions are for questions.  Answers are for answers.  The two should not be mixed.  If you want to add your own answer to your own question, you can do that.  Please remove your solution from your question.  It does not belong there.

Comment: If this is server-side code, then its disastrous to your server scalability to use any synchronous I/O anywhere other than at startup time.  It literally kills scalability.

Comment: @jfriend00 My edit was not intended to be an answer. I meant to drop that edit in and ask you how would I get this to work using either the async methods or promisify. It's also probably worth noting that I'm running node@8.11.3. If you have a solution I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: @jfriend00 Going off your last comment about sync vs async on the server. Are you suggesting one should wrap all synchronous code in a Promise? I understand you should probably use async code as much as possible as to prevent blocking but what about a situation where you don't have a built-in option for async function. Wrap it in a Promise?

Comment: It does you no good for scalability to wrap a synchronous function in a promise.  The synchronous implementation still steals the single Javascript thread and wrecks scalability.  I added an asynchronous implementation to my answer that will work in node version 8+.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Because readidir and stat are async I would expect them to return a Promise

First off, make sure you know the difference between an asynchronous function and an `async` function.  A function declared as `async` using that specific keyword in Javascript such as:

```
async function foo() {
    ...
}
```

does always return a promise (per the definition of a function declared with the `async` keyword).

But an asynchronous function such as `fs.readdir()` may or may not return a promise, depending upon its internal design.  In this particular case, the original implementation of the `fs` module in node.js only uses callbacks, not promises (its design predates the existence of promises in node.js).  Its functions are asynchronous, but not declared as `async` and thus it uses regular callbacks, not promises.

So, you have to either use the callbacks or "promisify" the interface to convert it into something that returns a promise so you can use `await` with it.

There is an [experimental interface in node.js v10](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) that offers built-in promises for the fs module.

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

fsp.readdir(...).then(...)
```

---

There are lots of options for promisifying functions in an earlier version of node.js.  You can do it function by function using [util.promisify()](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original):

```
const promisify = require('util').promisify;
const readdirP = promisify(fs.readdir);
const statP = promisify(fs.stat);
```

---

Since I'm not yet developing on node v10, I often use the Bluebird promise library and promisify the whole fs library at once:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

fs.readdirAsync(...).then(...)
```

---

To just list the sub-directories in a given directory, you could do this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const promisify = require('util').promisify;
const readdirP = promisify(fs.readdir);
const statP = promisify(fs.stat);

const root = path.join(__dirname, process.argv[2]);

// utility function for sequencing through an array asynchronously
function sequence(arr, fn) {
    return arr.reduce((p, item) => {
        return p.then(() => {
            return fn(item);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
}

function listDirs(rootDir) {
    const dirsOfCurrentDir = new Map();
    return readdirP(rootDir).then(files => {
        return sequence(files, f => {
            let fullPath = path.join(rootDir, f);
            return statP(fullPath).then(stats => {
                if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                    dirsOfCurrentDir.set(f, rootDir)
                }
            });
        });
    }).then(() => {
        return dirsOfCurrentDir;
    });  
}

listDirs(root).then(m => {
    for (let [f, dir] of m) {
        console.log(f);
    }
});
```

---

Here's a more general implementation that lists files and offers several options for both what to list and how to present the results:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const promisify = require('util').promisify;
const readdirP = promisify(fs.readdir);
const statP = promisify(fs.stat);

const root = path.join(__dirname, process.argv[2]);

// options takes the following:
//     recurse: true | false - set to true if you want to recurse into directories (default false)
//     includeDirs: true | false - set to true if you want directory names in the array of results
//     sort: true | false - set to true if you want filenames sorted in alpha order
//     results: can have any one of the following values
//              "arrayOfFilePaths" - return an array of full file path strings for files only (no directories included in results)
//              "arrayOfObjects" - return an array of objects {filename: "foo.html", rootdir: "//root/whatever", full: "//root/whatever/foo.html"}

// results are breadth first

// utility function for sequencing through an array asynchronously
function sequence(arr, fn) {
    return arr.reduce((p, item) => {
        return p.then(() => {
            return fn(item);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
}

function listFiles(rootDir, opts = {}, results = []) {
    let options = Object.assign({recurse: false, results: "arrayOfFilePaths", includeDirs: false, sort: false}, opts);

    function runFiles(rootDir, options, results) {
        return readdirP(rootDir).then(files => {
            let localDirs = [];
            if (options.sort) {
                files.sort();
            }
            return sequence(files, fname => {
                let fullPath = path.join(rootDir, fname);
                return statP(fullPath).then(stats => {
                    // if directory, save it until after the files so the resulting array is breadth first
                    if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                        localDirs.push({name: fname, root: rootDir, full: fullPath, isDir: true});
                    } else {
                        results.push({name: fname, root: rootDir, full: fullPath, isDir: false});
                    }
                });
            }).then(() => {
                // now process directories
                if (options.recurse) {
                    return sequence(localDirs, obj => {
                        // add directory to results in place right before its files
                        if (options.includeDirs) {
                            results.push(obj);
                        }
                        return runFiles(obj.full, options, results);
                    });
                } else {
                    // add directories to the results (after all files)
                    if (options.includeDirs) {
                        results.push(...localDirs);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }

    return runFiles(rootDir, options, results).then(() => {
        // post process results based on options
        if (options.results === "arrayOfFilePaths") {
            return results.map(item => item.full);
        } else {
            return results;
        }
    });
}

// get flat array of file paths, 
//     recursing into directories, 
//     each directory sorted separately
listFiles(root, {recurse: true, results: "arrayOfFilePaths", sort: true, includeDirs: false}).then(list => {
    for (const f of list) {
        console.log(f);
    }
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

You can copy this code into a file and run it, passing `.` as an argument to list the directory of the script or any subdirectory name you want to list.

If you wanted fewer options (such as no recursion or directory order not preserved), this code could be reduced significantly and perhaps made a little faster (run some async operations in parallel).

Comment: I'd suggest to update the answer with `require('fs').promises` example since it likely will be applicable for future readers.

Comment: @estus - Will do.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield - I added an implementation to my answer.  Because I wasn't sure what type of options you wanted, I wrote a generic version that accepts a number of options so you can determine if you want to recurse into directories, if you want directories included in the results, if you want each directory sorted and if you want just an array of filepaths or if you want an object that gives you filename, rootdir and a directory flag.