# node.js then() not working

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I am new to node.js so I am trying to understand promises and wait on node.js. I want to print the file note.txt.

Here is my code

```
    var fs = require('fs');

    fs.readFile('note.txt','utf8').then(contents => console.log(contents))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

When I run above code. I get the following error.

```
fs.readFile('note.txt','utf8').then(contents => console.log(contents))

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/nodeApps/test/index.js:13:31)
        at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
        at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

And I try another method for the same thing.

```
var fs = require('fs');

async function  read_file(){
  var file_data = await  fs.readFile('note.txt','utf8');
    return file_data;

}
console.log(read_file());
```

And I get following error

```
Promise { <pending> }
(node:6532) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
```

I get the same error when I run with --harmony. I m not sure if there is bug on my code or what is wrong. Please help me understand.

My Environment 
Node version: v8.9.0

node -p process.versions.v8: 6.1.534.46

Comment: `readFile` simply doesn't return a promise (in fact it returns `undefined`, according to the error you are getting). It only accepts a callback. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback . There are however third party modules that wrap native Node APIs in promises.

Comment: @FelixKling [Not just third party ones](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS: Confusion about async "readdir" and "stat"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180577/nodejs-confusion-about-async-readdir-and-stat)

Comment: @FelixKling [Not at all](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api).

Comment: @Bergi: ah, didn’t realize they already added it, I thought they were still working on it. Who can keep up these days :P not sure how it feel about experimental APIs though :D

Comment: @FelixKling Oh right there's also the `fs.promises` API, but `util.promisify` is stable.

Comment: @Bergi ah, must have looked at estus’ link (phone). Anyways, I didn’t know about `utils.promisify` either. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the answers. I learned that function must return promise in order to use then() and catch(). So the code should be like this

```
var fs = require('fs');

  function  read_file(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         fs.readFile('note.txt','utf8',function(err,file){
            if(err){
                return reject(err);
            }else{
                resolve(file);
            }
        });
    });


}

read_file().then(
    (data)=>{
        console.log('success: '+data);
    }
).catch((err)=>{
    console.log('error: ',err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting errors because [`fs.readfile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) doesn't return a promise; hence `then` doesn't exist. For you to use the function as a promise, you will need to wrap it up as a promise; you could use something like [`bluebird`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) or [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

Comment: is there a method to check if function returns a promise or not?

Comment: @KrishnaKarki The most reliable method is to read the documentation. This is one reason why javascript libraries are often very well documented (often with very fancy websites) compared to languages like Java where you can discover this from the syntax itself (hence your IDE can suggest intellisense) where library documentation are usually just what Javadoc generates

Answer (score 1):

If you use `NodeJs` v10, try [fs.promises](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api):

```
var fs = require('fs').promises; // v10.0 use require('fs/promises')

fs.readFile('note.txt','utf8').then(contents => console.log(contents))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

If not, use [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options):

```
// This code can use for node v10 or lowwer
var fs = require('fs');

var data = fs.readFileSync('a.json');
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use the async await

```
function (async  err => {
    if (err) {
       console.err ....}

    await .... <other function included or comes after then .>
    await ... <other function included>
})
```