# List files in a directory with fs.readdir & fs.stat and push to array

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, stat, readdir

I am trying to get list of files in a directory with help of fs.readdir & fs.stat (NodeJS version 9.8.0) and push the list to JSON array but it does not get populated. I am able to do it with synchronous methods ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019316/chaining-fs-readdir-with-a-then-to-return-an-array)) but I would like to get this done with asynchronous ones.
With some googling around came to know that this has something to do with callbacks. By the time callbacks finish the response is already sent (please correct if this understanding is wrong).
Following is the original code written:

```
var dirToRead = "allfiles";
app.get('/getDownloadFilesList', (req, res)=>{
 var allFilesInfo = [];
 fs.readdir(dirToRead,(err, files)=>{
  var allFilesInfo = [];
    files.forEach(function(file,index){
      fs.stat(dirToRead+"/"+file, (err,stats)=>{
        (err) => {return console.err(err)}
        allFilesInfo.push({"Count":index,"fileName":file,"fileSize":stats.size});
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Then I tried to use promisify with util package of NodeJS but no luck. Can someone please assist here.

```
const myUtil = require('util')
var dirToRead = "allfiles";
app.get('/getDownloadFilesList', (req, res)=>{
  var allFilesInfo = [];
  const readdir = myUtil.promisify(fs.readdir);
  const stat = myUtil.promisify(fs.stat);
  readdir(dirToRead).then((files)=>{
    files.forEach(function(file,index){
      stat(dirToRead+"/"+file).then(function(stats){
        allFilesInfo.push({"Count":index,"fileName":file,"fileSize":stats.size});
      }).catch((err)=>{
        (err) => {return console.err(err)}
      });
    });
  }).catch((err)=>{
    (err) => {return console.err(err)}
  });
  console.log(allFilesInfo);
  res.send(allFilesInfo);
});
```

Comment: Do you need a list containing all files in a directory and sub directories?

Comment: yes and further I would like to display the list in an HTML page with downloadable links.

Answer (score 0):

You are not awaiting the loop in the callback, so `res.send` happens before any of the `stat`s is done. The simplest would be using `Promise.all()`

```
const readdir = myUtil.promisify(fs.readdir);
const stat = myUtil.promisify(fs.stat);

app.get("/getDownloadFilesList", (req, res)=>{
  readdir(dirToRead).then(files => {
    Promise.all(files.map(x => stat(`${dirToRead}/${file}`)))
      .then(stats => stats.map((s, i) => {
           if (s.isFile()) return {"Count":i,"fileName":files[i],"fileSize":s.size});
           else return null;
        })
        .filter(x=> x!= null)
      ) 
      .then(fileInfos => res.send(fileInfos))
      .catch(e => res.sendStatus(400));
  });
});
```

BTW NodeJS 9 is quite outdated, you should probably move to a newer version, which also has an `fs` module supporting promises.

Comment: I will upgrade to the latest version for sure. Is this promise bluebird version or node util?

Comment: The fs promises api is available since NodeJS v10 and uses native promises. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api